# Find the power series expansion using the Generalized Binomial Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I need to find the power series expansion of $$(2-3x)^{-1/3}$$
By using the Generalized Binomial Theorem: 
$$(1+x)^m= \sum_{n\geq0}^{n}\dbinom{m}{n}x^n$$

I am told to use the following definition of binomial coefficients where m and n are real numbers:
$$\dbinom{m}{n} = \frac{m(m-1)..(m-n+1)}{n!}$$

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the formula...
\begin{align*}
 (2-3x)^{-1/3} &= 2^{-1/3}\big(1 + (-\tfrac{3x}{2})\big)^{-1/3}\\
 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]2}\bigg(1 + (-\tfrac13)(-\tfrac{3x}{2}) + \frac{(-\frac13)(-\frac43)}{2!}(-\tfrac{3x}{2})^2 + \frac{(-\frac13)(-\frac43)(-\frac73)}{3!}(-\tfrac{3x}{2})^3+\cdots \bigg)\\
 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]2}\bigg(1 + \frac x2 + \frac{x^2}2 + \frac{7x^3}{12} \bigg) + O(x^4),
\end{align*}
valid for $|-\frac{3x}{2}|<1$, i.e., for $|x|<\frac23$.

---

**Note:** If you are unfamiliar with the [big-Oh notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) (${}+O(x^4)$ above), this simply represents an "error" no bigger than some constant times $x^4$ (recall that for $x$ in the range of convergence, higher powers are smaller). If this is confusing, just substitute the more hand-wavy "${}+\cdots$" instead.